# Does the order of the Cases in a Switch statement have an impact on speed of execution in Swift?

Tags: swift

Given that a case is statistically more probable than the others, would the execution be quicker if that "case" was put first in a Switch statement?

Logically that should be the case, but I've been running some benchmarks, and I can't see much difference.
Is Switch/Case the best way to make use of the fact that a "case" is more probable than others?

Comment: If you could add your test code (even just the switch statement), that might help people to discuss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple to test:

```
struct MyInteger {
    let value: Int
}

func ~=(a: Int, b: MyInteger) -> Bool {
    println("Evaluating pattern \(a)")

    return (a == b.value)
}

for i in 0...3 {
    let number = MyInteger(value: i)

    switch (number) {
        case 0:
            println("Case 0")
        case 1:
            println("Case 1")
        case 2:
            println("Case 2")
        default:
            println("Default branch")
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Evaluating pattern 0
Case 0
Evaluating pattern 0
Evaluating pattern 1
Case 1
Evaluating pattern 0
Evaluating pattern 1
Evaluating pattern 2
Case 2
Evaluating pattern 0
Evaluating pattern 1
Evaluating pattern 2
Default branch
```

So, the order of `case` statements matters and they are evaluated only until we find one evaluating to `true`.

This is also the reason why the `default` statement must always be the last (this is not enforced in languages like Java or C where `switch` is just a jump table).

Every `case` is a call to a pattern matching function `~=` (or more of them).

Answer (score 0):

This proves that cases are evaluated in the order they are written:

```
func testing(a : Int)->Int{
    println(a)
    return a
}

let x = 2

switch x {
    case testing(1) :
        println("one")
    case testing(2) :
        println("two")
    case testing(3) :
        println("three")
    case testing(4) :
        println("four")
    default:
        println("Default")
}
```

this prints:

```
1
2
two
```

If you want to evaluate the following cases, then use the keyword `fallthrough`